# Is it safe to use "Iguana Tex"? Why does it trigger a virus report?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, antimalware, opensource

I have used [Iguana Tex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) in the past to insert Latex equations into my power point presentations. Lately, it triggers a response from the virus check programs. According to the developer, it is a 'false positive'

> Recently, several anti-virus softwares and firewalls have started reporting IguanaTex_v1_55.ppam as malware, sometimes even blocking download. After careful review of the code, I believe that these are false positives (more details at the bottom of this page).

At the bottom of the page, he continues:

> More details regarding malware detections: As can be seen on virustotal.com's analysis, a binary component containing macros I wrote (or included after checking they were safe) is being flagged as suspicious. You can check the content of all macros in the analysis. If someone has a clue how to avoid such false positives, please contact me.

What's going on here? Is this safe plugin safe to use? Why would it be flagged as suspicious?

---

IMHO, if someone put malware into the code, I doubt they'd maintain the website and a product so openly for several years. But it says "dangerous!"

Comment: Scareware claims something harmless if malware. Who would have thought.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Just to make sure, did you forget your /sarc tag?

Comment: unfortunately, we cannot perform code reviews to determine if this is safe - the developer is aware of the problem, has exposed the source code for review, and explains why there is a problem - an analyst would have to review everything and support or counter the dev's claims